# Dummy variable for Last Item in Group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe such as the following, how can I add a column indicating that the record is the last item for the id.

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID' :["A"] *5 +[ "B"] *2 + ["C"] * 4,
                    'Year': [2017] * 4 +[2018] + [2017, 2019] + [2019] *2 +[2020] * 2,
                    'Quarter': [1,2,3,4,1,3,2,3,4,1,2]})


    ID  Year    Quarter
0   A   2017    1
1   A   2017    2
2   A   2017    3
3   A   2017    4
4   A   2018    1
5   B   2017    3
6   B   2019    2
7   C   2019    3
8   C   2019    4
9   C   2020    1
10  C   2020    2
```

Desired:

```
    ID  Year    Quarter Last
0   A   2017    1       0
1   A   2017    2       0
2   A   2017    3       0
3   A   2017    4       0
4   A   2018    1       1
5   B   2017    3       0
6   B   2019    2       1
7   C   2019    3       0
8   C   2019    4       0
9   C   2020    1       0
10  C   2020    2       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `df['ID']` not equal to its next entry by using [`.ne()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`.shift(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and then change this Boolean series to 0, 1 series by casting from Boolean type to integer type, as follows:

```
df['last'] = df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift(-1)).astype(int)


print(df)

   ID  Year  Quarter  last
0   A  2017        1     0
1   A  2017        2     0
2   A  2017        3     0
3   A  2017        4     0
4   A  2018        1     1
5   B  2017        3     0
6   B  2019        2     1
7   C  2019        3     0
8   C  2019        4     0
9   C  2020        1     0
10  C  2020        2     1
```

Comment: Thanks. For this solution, what happens to the last record of the data set?

Comment: @JoshuaFarina  The last record can still be set correctly even it has no next entry.  See the demo result from true program execution run above.

Comment: Your concern is valid.  So long as the `ID` has a valid value other than NaN, it can check with inequality of the shifted in NaN value.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `series.duplicated` with `keep='last` and subtract it from 1

```
df['Last'] = 1-df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last')
#df['Last'] = 1-df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last').astype(int)
```

---

```
   ID  Year  Quarter  Last
0   A  2017        1     0
1   A  2017        2     0
2   A  2017        3     0
3   A  2017        4     0
4   A  2018        1     1
5   B  2017        3     0
6   B  2019        2     1
7   C  2019        3     0
8   C  2019        4     0
9   C  2020        1     0
10  C  2020        2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative -

```
df['Last'] = 0
def add_id(s):
    s.iloc[-1] =1
    return s
df['Last'] = df.groupby('ID')['Last'].transform(add_id)
```